# Store data in database from fingerprint device

Tags: php, mysql, fingerprint

Does anyone know how this device work:

https://www.amazon.in/Idemia-Safran-Morpho-Fingerprint-Scanner/dp/B01M0O2RUW

This is basically a fingerprint sensor and it store user data but I want to know how it works?

How I can store data from this device into my database?

I want to built an application which register users by their fingerprint.

Comment: Were you able to get this done? I am working on something similar and am struck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how they work:

https://www.androidauthority.com/how-fingerprint-scanners-work-670934

There's a driver at Morpho's website:

https://www.morpho.com/en/biometric-terminals/desktop-devices/fingerprint-devices/morphosmart-1300-series

and you can request their SDK. You'll probably have to write something in C/C++/.NET/Java to interface with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

These devices have **SDK** and documentation to read data from device memory.

[check this link](https://usa.morpho.com/biometric-terminals/software-applications-and-development-kits)

as mentioned in the brochure, this device does not support PHP. you can try using .NET or Java environments.